# c# multiply opening windowsform

Tags: c#, drawing

I have a problem. I want to open windows form multiply times with using only one button one time.
I draw something in different places on my form and form is opened when i click the button.
I would like to when I click the button the form will open and close and open again but with different picture(because I choose points randomly) 
Could you help me? I cant fix it alone :(
Here is my code to draw something

```
    public void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        int x1, y1, x2, y2;
        Random losowa1 = new Random();
        x1 = losowa1.Next(0, 200);
        Random losowa2 = new Random();
        y1 = losowa2.Next(0, 480);
        Random losowa3 = new Random();
        x2 = losowa1.Next(300, 500);
        Random losowa4 = new Random();
        y2 = losowa2.Next(0, 480);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, x1, y1, 100, 100);
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, x2, y2, 100, 100);
     }
```

And here I open the form

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
            {
                Form1 OknoStart = new Form1();
                OknoStart.ShowDialog();
            }
      }
```

Hope you will help me or will show me proper way...
Thanks!

Comment: Well, if you want to open the form multiple times, I suggest you don't use `ShowDialog` as that opens the new form as a modal form.

Comment: You don't need to re-load the Form. You need a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. Set an `Interval` that fits your needs, subscribe to the Timer `Tick` event. In the `Tick` event handler, `Invalidate()` the Form. This will cause the re-paint of its surface. Meaning, the `Paint()` event code will be executed each time `form1.Invalidate()` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

form1:

```
 private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            int x1, y1, x2, y2;
            Random losowa1 = new Random();
            x1 = losowa1.Next(0, 200);
            Random losowa2 = new Random();
            y1 = losowa2.Next(0, 480);
            Random losowa3 = new Random();
            x2 = losowa1.Next(300, 500);
            Random losowa4 = new Random();
            y2 = losowa2.Next(0, 480);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, x1, y1, 100, 100);
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, x2, y2, 100, 100);

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            this.Close();
        }
```

button1:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i=0;i<2;i++) {
                Form1 form1 = new Form1();
                form1.ShowDialog();

            }
        }
```

Comment: It works...Thank you so much. It was so simple I dont know why I didnt think about it...

Comment: I have one more question. Do you know how I can save the view of form to the file? As an image? I would like to put it in special folder.
Thank you one more time!

Comment: this is sample code  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height))
            {
                this.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size));
                bmp.Save(@"D:\Stackimage\sample" + i + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
            }
        }